# MD5 Hash- Keystore no longer at ~/.android/debug.keystore

Tags: android, maps, md5

I'm trying to find the MD5 Hash so I can start a google maps tutorial.

So I first need to get the MD5, but there was an update recently for mac android SDK.

I've been using this tutorial
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html

I just need to find the debug.keystore so I can continue. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new keystore with keytool.

According to the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert), here's a keytool command that generates a private key:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore \
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```